# Как вставить ссылку в html?

Tags: html, теги, href

Есть тег *`[product_review_link]`* вместо которого в `html шаблоне` письма сайтом рассылки должна подставляться ссылка на сайт, помогите пожалуйста мне её туда втулить))

`href="[product_review_link]"` - естественно не работает.
Ума не приложу, как задать нормальный вопрос ***Google*** по этому поводу.

Comment: Добавь, пожалуйста, пример своего кода. (только не в ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, что правильно используете html-тэг:

```
<a href="https://google.ru">Cсылка</a>
```

Ссылка на источник: [оригинал](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

P.S. Если ссылка внешняя, то в `href` должен быть указан `https://` или `http://`

Comment: Внутренние ссылки лучше делать относительными!